# Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to push

```
data.push({"country": "IN"});
```

as new id and value to a json string. but it gives the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function

data{"name":"ananta","age":"15"}
```

Advance Thanks for your reply

Comment: Because `data` is not an `Array`. If it's an `object`, just set `date.country = 'IN'`. If it's a "JSON string", you better deserialize it first.

Comment: `data.country = 'IN'`

Comment: Ensure you don't do "data = data.push(...)". This also causes the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

To use the push function of an Array your var needs to be an Array.

Change `data{"name":"ananta","age":"15"}` to following:

```
var data = [
    { 
        "name": "ananta",
        "age": "15",
        "country": "Atlanta"
    }
];

data.push({"name": "Tony Montana", "age": "99"});

data.push({"country": "IN"});

..
```

The containing Array Items will be typeof Object and you can do following:

`var text = "You are " + data[0]->age + " old and come from " + data[0]->country;`

Notice: Try to be consistent. In my example, one array contained object properties `name` and `age` while the other only contains `country`. If I iterate this with `for` or `forEach` then I can't always check for one property, because my example contains Items that changing.

Perfect would be: `data.push({ "name": "Max", "age": "5", "country": "Anywhere" } );`

So you can iterate and always can get the properties, even if they are empty, null or undefined.

*edit*

Cool stuff to know:

```
var array = new Array();
```

is similar to:

```
var array = [];
```

Also:

```
var object = new Object();
```

is similar to:

```
var object = {};
```

You also can combine them:

```
var objectArray = [{}, {}, {}];
```

Answer (score 16):

Your `data` variable contains an object, not an array, and objects do not have the `push` function as the error states. To do what you need you can do this:

```
data.country = 'IN';
```

Or

```
data['country'] = 'IN';
```

Comment: Suppose I have country as a variable and I want to pass variable value, How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: @HarshPatel the second example using bracket notation can handle variables: `var propertyName = 'country'; data[propertyName] = 'IN';`

Answer (score 11):

Also make sure that the name of the variable is not some kind of a language keyword.
For instance, the following produces the same type of error:

```
var history = [];
history.push("what a mess");
```

replacing it for:

```
var history123 = [];
history123.push("pray for a better language");
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 8):

you can use push method only if the object is an array:

```
var data = new Array();
data.push({"country": "IN"}).
```

OR

```
data['country'] = "IN"
```

if it's just an object you can use

```
data.country = "IN";
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you set it as

```
var data = [];
```

but after some time you made it like:

```
data = 'some thing which is not an array';
```

then
`data.push('')` will not work as it is not an array anymore.

Answer (score 5):

One things to remember push work only with `array[]` not `object{}`.

If you want to add object `o` inside inside `n` like that :

```js
a = {
   b:"c",
   D:"e",
   F: {
      g:"h",
      I:"j",
      k: {
         l:"m"
      }
   }
}

a.F.k.n = { o: "p" };
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This Code $scope.DSRListGrid.data = data; this one for source data

```
            for (var prop in data[0]) {
                if (data[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    $scope.ListColumns.push(
                            {
                                "name": prop,
                                "field": prop,
                                "width": 150,
                                "headerCellClass": 'font-12'
                            }
                    );
                }
            }
            console.log($scope.ListColumns);
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you **push** into an Array only
and if their is error like **Uncaught TypeError: data.push** is not a function**
then check for type of **data**
you can do this by **consol.log(data)**
hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

let dataArray = [{'id':1,'code':'ABC'},{'id':1,'code':'ABC'},{'id':2,'code':'ABC'}]

```
    let obj = {};
  dataArray.forEach(task => {        
    task.id in obj ? obj[task.employee_id].push(task):
    obj = {
      ...obj,
      [task.employee_id]: [task],
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain why your answer should fix the issue ? Please [edit] your question to be more precise

Answer (score 0):

Define new empty JSON array as

```
 private unpaidChecksTable: any = [{ }];
```

Then you can store/initialise data of your required format like this:

```
this.data.push({
        'first_name': this.data[i]['first_name'],
        'last_name': this.data[i]['last_name'],
        'email': this.data[i]['email'],
        'mobile': this.data[i]['mobile'],
        'referenceNo': this.data[i]['referenceNo'],
        'status': this.data[i]['status']
});
```