# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at products.js:25

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope

> angular.js:13920 TypeError: $scope.products.push is not a function

```
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
    .constant("baseUrl", "http://localhost:2403/dashboard/products/properties/")
    .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $http, baseUrl) {
        $scope.products = [];


    $scope.displayMode = "list";
    $scope.currentProduct = null;

    $scope.listProducts = function () {
    $http.get(baseUrl)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.error = error;
            $scope.displayMode = "Error";
        });
    }
    $scope.deleteProduct = function (product) {
        $scope.products.splice($scope.products.indexOf(product), 1);
    }

    $scope.createProduct = function (product) {
        $scope.products.push(product);
        $scope.displayMode = "list";
    }

    $scope.updateProduct = function (product) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
            if ($scope.products[i].id == product.id) {
                $scope.data.products[i] = product;
                break;
            }
        }
        $scope.displayMode = "list";
    }

    $scope.editOrCreateProduct = function (product) {
        $scope.currentProduct =
            product ? angular.copy(product) : {};
            $scope.displayMode = "edit";
    }

    $scope.saveEdit = function (product) {
        if (angular.isDefined(product.id)) {
            $scope.updateProduct(product);
        } else {
            $scope.createProduct(product);
        }
    } 

    $scope.cancelEdit = function () {
        $scope.currentProduct = {};
        $scope.displayMode = "list";
    }
    $scope.listProducts();
});`
```

I will be happy if provided with answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696572/uncaught-typeerror-data-push-is-not-a-function

Comment: First thing to do, log `$scope.products`. It has no `push` method, meaning it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

To use the push function your variable  need to be an Array.

Though you have defined it `$scope.products = [];`

Can you double check on what you are getting in data.

```
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.products = data;
})
```

Maybe data is not of array type.

Comment: Data is from a mongodb database http://localhost:2403/dashboard/products/properties/

Comment: ok.. try to verify the type of data as mentioned by Nihar Sarkar??? Ideally response should never be in array form. There must be something like data.data or data.products (whatever your are getting in the response) which should be holding your products data.

Comment: If it's from Mongo, it can be an object. Don't suppose it is an array and log it.

Answer (score 0):

To tell if a variable is an array you can do console.log(typeof [variable]); to see what type it is, or alternatively just console log the variable to see the contents.
That variable should be an Array .

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer: from the responses I looked at the URL to the MongoDB database and changed it from "http://localhost:2403/dashboard/products/properties/"  to
"http://localhost:2403/products" and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.