# ng-bind-html working but throwing TypeError

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the line of code with the `ng-bind-html`:

`<span ng-bind-html="text"></span>`

Here is the stack trace:

```
angular.js:13236 TypeError: bindings.push is not a function
at Function.$$addBindingInfo (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8004:18)
at ngBindHtmlLink (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:23505:18)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9492:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8978:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8226:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8229:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8229:13)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8973:24)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8226:13)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8973:24) <span ng-bind-html="text" class="ng-binding">
```

The controller code:

```
(function (module) {
mifosX.controllers = _.extend(module, {
    MainController: function (scope, location, sessionManager, translate, $rootScope, localStorageService, keyboardManager, $idle, tmhDynamicLocale, 
              uiConfigService, $http) {

        $http.get('release.json').success(function(data) {
            scope.version = data.version;
            scope.releasedate = data.releasedate;
        });

        scope.islogofoldernamefetched = false;
        scope.islogofoldernameconfig = false;
        scope.isFaviconPath = false;
        scope.isHeaderLogoPath = false;
        scope.isBigLogoPath = false;
        scope.isLargeLogoPath = false;

        if(!scope.islogofoldernamefetched && $rootScope.tenantIdentifier && $rootScope.tenantIdentifier != "default"){
            scope.islogofoldernamefetched = true;
            $http.get('scripts/config/LogoConfig.json').success(function(datas) {
                for(var i in datas){
                    var data = datas[i];
                    if(data.tenantIdentifier != undefined && data.tenantIdentifier == $rootScope.tenantIdentifier){
                        if(data.logofoldername != undefined && data.logofoldername != ""){
                            scope.islogofoldernameconfig = true;
                            scope.logofoldername = data.logofoldername;
                            if(data.faviconPath){
                                scope.isFaviconPath = true;
                                scope.faviconPath = data.faviconPath;
                            }
                            if(data.bigLogoPath){
                                scope.isBigLogoPath = true;
                                scope.bigLogoPath = data.bigLogoPath;
                            }
                            if(data.headerLogoPath){
                                scope.isHeaderLogoPath = true;
                                scope.headerLogoPath = data.headerLogoPath;
                            }
                            if(data.largeLogoPath){
                                scope.isLargeLogoPath = true;
                                scope.largeLogoPath = data.largeLogoPath;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        uiConfigService.init();
        //hides loader
        scope.domReady = true;
        scope.activity = {};
        scope.activityQueue = [];
        if (localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('Location')) {
            scope.activityQueue = localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('Location');
        }
        scope.loadSC = function () {
            if (!localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('searchCriteria'))
                localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('searchCriteria', {})
            scope.searchCriteria = localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('searchCriteria');
        };
        scope.saveSC = function () {
            localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('searchCriteria', scope.searchCriteria);
        };
        scope.loadSC();
        scope.setDf = function () {
            if (localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('dateformat')) {
                scope.dateformat = localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('dateformat');
            } else {
                localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('dateformat', 'dd MMMM yyyy');
                scope.dateformat = 'dd MMMM yyyy';
            }
            scope.df = scope.dateformat;
            scope.dft = scope.dateformat + ' ' + 'HH:mm:ss'
        };

        scope.updateDf = function(dateFormat){
            localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('dateformat', dateFormat);
            scope.dateformat = dateFormat;
            scope.setDf();
        };
        scope.setDf();
        $rootScope.setPermissions = function (permissions) {
            $rootScope.permissionList = permissions;
            localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('userPermissions', permissions);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('permissionsChanged')
        };

        $rootScope.hasPermission = function (permission) {
            permission = permission.trim();
            //FYI: getting all permissions from localstorage, because if scope changes permissions array will become undefined
            $rootScope.permissionList = localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('userPermissions');
            //If user is a Super user return true
            if ($rootScope.permissionList && _.contains($rootScope.permissionList, "ALL_FUNCTIONS")) {
                return true;
            } else if ($rootScope.permissionList && permission && permission != "") {
                //If user have all read permission return true
                if (permission.substring(0, 5) == "READ_" && _.contains($rootScope.permissionList, "ALL_FUNCTIONS_READ")) {
                    return true;
                } else if (_.contains($rootScope.permissionList, permission)) {
                    //check for the permission if user doesn't have any special permissions
                    return true;
                } else {
                    //return false if user doesn't have permission
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                //return false if no value assigned to has-permission directive
                return false;
            }
            ;
        };

        scope.$watch(function () {
            return location.path();
        }, function () {
            scope.activity = location.path();
            scope.activityQueue.push(scope.activity);
            localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('Location', scope.activityQueue);
        });

        //Logout the user if Idle
        scope.started = false;
        scope.$on('$idleTimeout', function () {
            scope.logout();
            $idle.unwatch();
            scope.started = false;
        });

        // Log out the user when the window/tab is closed.
        window.onunload = function () {
            scope.logout();
            $idle.unwatch();
            scope.started = false;
        };

        scope.start = function (session) {
            if (session) {
                $idle.watch();
                scope.started = true;
            }
        };

        scope.leftnav = false;
        scope.$on("UserAuthenticationSuccessEvent", function (event, data) {
            scope.authenticationFailed = false;
            scope.resetPassword = data.shouldRenewPassword;
            if (sessionManager.get(data)) {
                scope.currentSession = sessionManager.get(data);
                scope.start(scope.currentSession);
                if (scope.currentSession.user && scope.currentSession.user.userPermissions) {
                    $rootScope.setPermissions(scope.currentSession.user.userPermissions);
                }
                location.path('/home').replace();
            } else {
                scope.loggedInUserId = data.userId;
            }
            ;
        });

        var setSearchScopes = function () {
            var all = {name: "label.search.scope.all", value: "clients,clientIdentifiers,groups,savings,loans"};
            var clients = {
                name: "label.search.scope.clients.and.clientIdentifiers",
                value: "clients,clientIdentifiers"
            };
            var groups = {
                name: "label.search.scope.groups.and.centers",
                value: "groups"
            };
            var savings = {name: "label.input.adhoc.search.loans", value: "loans"};
            var loans = {name: "label.search.scope.savings", value: "savings"};
            scope.searchScopes = [all,clients,groups,loans,savings];
            scope.currentScope = all;
        }

        setSearchScopes();

        scope.changeScope = function (searchScope) {
            scope.currentScope = searchScope ;
        }

        scope.search = function () {
            var resource;
            var searchString=scope.search.query;
            var exactMatch=false;
            if(searchString != null){
                searchString = searchString.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, '');
                var n = searchString.localeCompare(scope.search.query);
                if(n!=0)
                {
                    exactMatch=true;
                }
            }
            location.path('/search/' + searchString).search({exactMatch: exactMatch, resource: scope.currentScope.value});

        };
        scope.text = '<span>Kanzu Banking is designed by <a href="https://kanzucode.com">Kanzu Code</a> ' +
        'to ease the management of savings & loans for SACCOS and Microfinance institutions</span>';

        scope.logout = function () {
            scope.currentSession = sessionManager.clear();
            scope.resetPassword = false;
            location.path('/').replace();
        };

        scope.langs = mifosX.models.Langs;
        if (localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('Language')) {
            var temp = localStorageService.getFromLocalStorage('Language');
            for (var i in mifosX.models.Langs) {
                if (mifosX.models.Langs[i].code == temp.code) {
                    scope.optlang = mifosX.models.Langs[i];
                    tmhDynamicLocale.set(mifosX.models.Langs[i].code);
                    }
            }
        } else {
            scope.optlang = scope.langs[0];
            tmhDynamicLocale.set(scope.langs[0].code);
            }
        translate.use(scope.optlang.code);

        scope.isActive = function (route) {
            if (route == 'clients') {
                var temp = ['/clients', '/groups', '/centers'];
                for (var i in temp) {
                    if (temp[i] == location.path()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (route == 'acc') {
                var temp1 = ['/accounting', '/freqposting', '/accounting_coa', '/journalentry', '/accounts_closure', '/Searchtransaction', '/accounting_rules'];
                for (var i in temp1) {
                    if (temp1[i] == location.path()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (route == 'rep') {
                var temp2 = ['/reports/all', '/reports/clients', '/reports/loans', '/reports/funds', '/reports/accounting', 'reports/savings'];
                for (var i in temp2) {
                    if (temp2[i] == location.path()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (route == 'admin') {
                var temp3 = ['/users/', '/organization', '/system', '/products', '/global'];
                for (var i in temp3) {
                    if (temp3[i] == location.path()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                var active = route === location.path();
                return active;
            }
        };

        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+n', function () {
            location.path('/nav/offices');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+i', function () {
            location.path('/tasks');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+o', function () {
            location.path('/entercollectionsheet');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+c', function () {
            location.path('/createclient');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+g', function () {
            location.path('/creategroup');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+q', function () {
            location.path('/createcenter');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+f', function () {
            location.path('/freqposting');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+e', function () {
            location.path('/accounts_closure');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+j', function () {
            location.path('/journalentry');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+a', function () {
            location.path('/accounting');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+r', function () {
            location.path('/reports/all');
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+s', function () {
            document.getElementById('save').click();
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+r', function () {
            document.getElementById('run').click();
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+x', function () {
            document.getElementById('cancel').click();
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+l', function () {
            document.getElementById('logout').click();
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('alt+x', function () {
            document.getElementById('search').focus();
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+shift+h', function () {
            document.getElementById('help').click();
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+n', function () {
            document.getElementById('next').click();
        });
        keyboardManager.bind('ctrl+p', function () {
            document.getElementById('prev').click();
        });
        scope.changeLang = function (lang, $event) {
            translate.uses(lang.code);
            localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('Language', lang);
            tmhDynamicLocale.set(lang.code);
            scope.optlang = lang;
            };
        scope.helpf = function()
        {
            // first, create addresses array
        var addresses = ["https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/User+Setup","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Organization",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/System", "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=products&startIndex=0&where=docs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67141762","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=report&startIndex=0&where=docs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=accounting&startIndex=0&where=docs",  "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Clients",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Groups","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Centers",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/User+Manual","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Offices",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Holidays","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Employees",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Funds","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Bulk+Loan+Reassignment",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Currency+Configuration","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Standing+Instructions+History",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Data+Tables","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67895350",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Roles+and+Permissions","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Maker-Checker",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Hooks","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Audit+Trails",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Reports","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Manage+Scheduler+Jobs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Global+Configuration","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=account%20number%20preferences&startIndex=0&where=docs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=loan%20products&startIndex=0&where=docs","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=saving%20products&startIndex=0&where=docs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=charges&startIndex=0&where=docs","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=products%20mix&startIndex=0&where=docs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=fixed%20deposit%20products&startIndex=0&where=docs","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=recurring%20deposit%20products&startIndex=0&where=docs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67895308","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Add+Journal+Entries",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=search%20journal%20entries&startIndex=0&where=docs",  "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/dosearchsite.action?queryString=accounts%20linked&startIndex=0&where=docs",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Chart+of+Accounts+and+General+Ledger+Setup", "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Closing+Entries",
            "https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67895308","https://mifosforge.jira.com/wiki/display/docs/Accruals"]; 
        // array is huge, but working good
        // create second array with address models
        var addrmodels = ['/users/','/organization','/system','/products','/templates', '', '/accounting',
                            '/clients', '/groups','/centers','','/offices', '/holidays','/employees','/managefunds/',
                            '/bulkloan','/currconfig','/standinginstructions/history','/datatables','/codes','/admin/roles',
                            '/admin/viewmctasks','/hooks','/audit', '/reports','/jobs','/global','/accountnumberpreferences','/loanproducts',
                            '/savingproducts','/charges','/productmix', '/fixeddepositproducts','/recurringdepositproducts','/freqposting',
                            '/journalentry','/searchtransaction','/financialactivityaccountmappings','/accounting_coa', '/accounts_closure','/accounting_rules','/run_periodic_accrual'];
        // * text-based address-recognize system *
        var actualadr = location.absUrl();  // get full URL     
        var lastchar = 0;
        for( var i = 0; i<actualadr.length;i++)
            {

                if(actualadr.charAt(i) == '#')
                {
                    lastchar = i+1;                     
                    break;
                    // found '#' and save position of it
                }
            }//for

        var whereweare = actualadr.substring(lastchar); // cut full URL to after-'#' part

        // string after '#' is compared with model
        var addrfound = false;
        if(whereweare == '/reports/all' || whereweare == '/reports/clients' || whereweare == '/reports/loans' || whereweare == '/reports/savings' || whereweare == '/reports/funds' || whereweare == '/reports/accounting' || whereweare == '/xbrl'  )
                 {
                    window.open(addresses[5]);
                    addrfound = true;                   
                 }// '/reports/...' are exception -> link to Search in Documentation word 'report'
                 else{
                        for(var i = 0; i< addrmodels.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(i != 5 && i != 10)
                                {
                                    if(whereweare == addrmodels[i])
                                    {
                                            addrfound = true;
                                            window.open(addresses[i]);
                                            break;          
                                            // model found -> open address and break
                                    }
                                }                               
                        }//for
                      }//else
            if(addrfound == false) window.open(addresses[10]); // substring not matching to any model -> open start user manual page

        };//helpf

        sessionManager.restore(function (session) {
            scope.currentSession = session;
            scope.start(scope.currentSession);
            if (session.user != null && session.user.userPermissions) {
                $rootScope.setPermissions(session.user.userPermissions);
                localStorageService.addToLocalStorage('userPermissions', session.user.userPermissions);
            }
            ;
        });
    }
});
mifosX.ng.application.controller('MainController', [
    '$scope',
    '$location',
    'SessionManager',
    '$translate',
    '$rootScope',
    'localStorageService',
    'keyboardManager', '$idle',
    'tmhDynamicLocale',
    'UIConfigService',
    '$http',
    mifosX.controllers.MainController
]).run(function ($log) {
    $log.info("MainController initialized");
});
}(mifosX.controllers || {}));
```

Comment: Did you include ngSanitize module? Can you post your controller code?

Comment: `ngSanitize` is included.

Comment: Do you have a variable by the name of bindings?

Comment: Yes. In the controller we have `scope.text = '<span>...</span>'`

Comment: Can you post the relevant controller code for which you are using ng-bind-html?

Comment: I have posted it.

Comment: Shouldn't there be $ before many of the parameters. Try using $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.text)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input. I was able to crush this bug by resolving `angular-sanitize` to a version compatible with the `angular` version installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
//if bindings  is not defined, it will define it as an array 
bindings  = bindings  || [];

//Do the push operation
bindings.push(object);
```

for more details [uncaught typeerror: data push is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696572/uncaught-typeerror-data-push-is-not-a-function)