# assigning a variable to HTML selector , class

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wanted to assign a javascript variable in a html selector class. Is it possible? 
Ex.

```
var assign="hotel";
```

code below are all in javascript

```
<span class=assign></span>
```

Comment: Please elaborate, question is __not__ clear at all(IMHO good candidate to close)

Comment: What's this got to do with PHP?

Comment: okay sorry. ill reconstruct the question.

Comment: Post more code please and explain what do you mean by "assign a javascript variable in a html selector class" with example of desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign css class using java script variables. Please check the below code, it may help you. Here span will have class 'hotel'

```js
var assign="hotel";
document.write('<span class='+assign+'>test</span>');
```

Comment: this is what im looking for. So by that, span class is equal to <span class="hotel"> test</span> ??

Comment: thankss it worked. i need this for my star rating since it is loooping and i need a class to be unique

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with 3 classes, and a function that you call when you want to change (here is on a click on a button with `hotel-button` id).

**CSS Styles**

```
<style>
    .hotel {
        color: red;
    }

    .garage {
        color: blue;
    }

    .house {
        color: black;
    }

    ...
</style>
```

**JS (jQuery) function**

```
<script>
    function assignClass(assign) {
        $('.assign').removeClass('hotel house garage').addClass(assign);
    }
</script>
```

**use :**

```
<button id="hotel-button">hotel</button>
<script>
    $('#hotel-button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        assignClass('hotel');
    });
<script>
<span class="assign"></span>
```

Comment: thanks meloman. can i ask a question? i have an object 
ratings = {
  hotel_a : 2.8,
 
};
but when i push another object using 
ratings.push({hotel_b : 3.2}) it gives me ratings.push is not a function why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696572/uncaught-typeerror-data-push-is-not-a-function here is your answer I think.