# Push data into array of objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an Array of Objects, once the user fill out and click on the button with id: `'add'`, I want to push this data into the first master.review.

I tried with `push()` but I am getting 'list[0].review[j].push is not a function'.

I did some research and I saw I should do like this:

```
list[0].review[j] = newData
```

But not even this one is working. Plus I want to add data all the time the user wants to add something.

```js
let list = [

  {
    master: "Leo",
    review: [{
        name: 'Bob',
        text: 'good'
      },
      {
        name: 'Elly',
        text: 'ok ok'
      },

    ]

  },
  {
    master: "Emily",
    review: [{
        name: 'Greg',
        text: 'omg!'
      },
      {
        name: 'Joe',
        text: 'SO so..'
      },

    ]

  },
]

$('#add').on('click', function() {

  let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  let text = document.getElementById('text').value;

  let newData = [{
    name: name,
    text: text,
  }]


  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < list[i].review.length; j++) {
      list[0].review[j].push(newData)
      console.log(list)
    }

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
<input type="button" id="add" />
```

Comment: use `list[0].review.push(newData)`.

Comment: `review[#].push` is not a function.  `review.push` is.  `review` is an array of objects.  the inner objects are not arrays.  `push()` is an array operation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696572/uncaught-typeerror-data-push-is-not-a-function)

Comment: What's the logic here? How to you select to which review array you're going to add the new data? Is it always going to be the first one? or... are you trying yo push the new data to all review array ( in all objects in side `list`)?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to push into an `Object`. Method `push` is not available on type `Object`. `push` is available on type `Array` in javascript. Try below code

```
list[0].review.push(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of loop as you want to push the newData object into the `list[0]`. In order to push into the array use `push` function - `list[0].review.push(newData);`

```js
let list = [

  {
    master: "Leo",
    review: [{
        name: 'Bob',
        text: 'good'
      },
      {
        name: 'Elly',
        text: 'ok ok'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    master: "Emily",
    review: [{
        name: 'Greg',
        text: 'omg!'
      },
      {
        name: 'Joe',
        text: 'SO so..'
      },
    ]
  },
]

$('#add').on('click', function() {
  let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  let text = document.getElementById('text').value;

  let newData = {
    name: name,
    text: text,
  };

  list[0].review.push(newData);
  console.log(list[0].review);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
<input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Your Name" required/>
<input type="button" id="add" value= "add" />
```