# trouble adding a friend to the database (React/Firebase) -- "TypeError: Friends.push is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Thank you so much in advance for any help. Basically, I am trying to write code which allows a user to add a friend to their "friend list."

This is my addFriend function right now:

```
export function addFriend(userID, friendID) {

  ourDB.ref(`users/${userID}/Friends`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    var Friends = snapshot.val();

    console.log(userID)
    console.log("what up")
    console.log("type" + typeof Friends)
    console.log(Friends)
    //console.log(typeof Friends)
    //console.log(Friends.Friends)


    if(Friends && Friends.Friends){
      Friends.Friends.push(friendID);
    }
    else {
      Friends = {Friends: [friendID]}
    }

    ourDB.ref(`users/${userID}`).child('Friends').set({
          Friends
    })
  });
```

Unfortunately, the function is erroring when I yarn start at Friends.push. I get the message: "TypeError: Friends.Friends.push is not a function"

I'm not quite sure why this is happening, but basically typeof Friends is object and contains {Friends: Array(1)} one friend which I hard coded in.

Also, here is the output from the console:

G7dCfxkE6rSt3RoZMmt4bpCt6rS2 (current user id / my id logged in)
what up
type object
{Friends: Array(1)}

Thank you so so much!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: data.push is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696572/uncaught-typeerror-data-push-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I believe you're instantiating `Friends` as the value of snapshot, which may or may not be an array, correct? Have you tried in your null check changing the conditional to `if ( Friends !== null && Array.isArray(Friends) )`?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much Joel-- I tried it but it didn't allow me to enter the page anymore

Answer (score 0):

As per your console output, `Friends` is an object which has a key called `Friends` which holds an array.

```js
if(Friends && Friends.Friends){
  Friends.Friends.push(friendID);
}
else {
  Friends = {Friends: [friendID]}
}
```

Also, in your else block, assign the inner key object

Comment: Hi I'm sorry, now it is saying TypeError: Friends.Friends.push is not a function... do you know how to possibly fix this? thank you!

Comment: can you console log the following and show - console.log('Friends', Friends) .. console.log('Friends.Friends', Friends.Friends)

Comment: it says Friends.Friends Object // Friends: ["a0uL79bAGfQuexUqxTxo7M34qgt1"] // __proto__: Object // thank you!!

Comment: Friends => {Friends: {…}} => Friends: {Friends: Array(1)} __proto__: Object
 // Friends.Friends => {Friends: Array(1)} => {Friends: Array(1)}
=> Friends: ["a0uL79bAGfQuexUqxTxo7M34qgt1"]
__proto__: Object